# How to run linq query with select when a primary key column returns null and thus the related attribute is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following query:

```
    var ComplaintsQuery = _context.TblComplaints.Select(p => new
    {
        ComplaintId = p.ComplaintId,
        ClientId = p.ClientId,
        ClientFullName = p.Client.ClientFullName,
        Datecomplaintreceived = p.Datecomplaintreceived,
        StaffmemberId = p.StaffmemberId,
        StaffFullName = p.Staffmember.StaffFullName,
    }
    )?.AsQueryable();
```

The database table for complaints is such that in some rows, `clientId` is null, thus I am am unable to retrieve `ClientFullName`, similarly for `StaffFullname` and `StaffmemberId`.

Is there any way around this to have the query return null rather than a null exception which breaks the code?

Comment: Have you tried using either `p.ClientId == null ? null : p.Client.ClientFullName` or `p.Client?.FullName`? (I seem to remember that the latter wasn't supported at one point, but it may be now...)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jon Skeet's comment, the following code is functional with no null exception outputs.

```
        var ComplaintsQuery = _context.TblComplaints.Select(p => new
        {
            ComplaintId = p.ComplaintId,
            ClientId = p.ClientId,
            ClientFullName = p.ClientId == null ? null : p.Client.ClientFullName,
            Datecomplaintreceived = p.Datecomplaintreceived,
            StaffmemberId = p.StaffmemberId,
            StaffFullName = p.StaffmemberId == null ? null : p.Staffmember.StaffFullName,
        }
        )?.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: If you query directly against `_context.TblComplaints` these null checks shouldn't be necessary because the query is translated into SQL. If you do need them you're not showing the actual code. Likewise, `?.AsQueryable();` is not necessary. Always avoid redundant code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var ComplaintsQuery = (from p in _context.TblComplaints
                               select new
                               {
                                   ComplaintId = p.ComplaintId,
                                   ClientId = p.ClientId,
                                   ClientFullName = p.ClientId == null ? null : p.Client.ClientFullName,
                                   Datecomplaintreceived = p.Datecomplaintreceived,
                                   StaffmemberId = p.StaffmemberId,
                                   StaffFullName = p.Staffmember == null ? null : p.Staffmember.StaffFullName,
                               }).AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you use EntityFramework Core it won't give you exception on `null` but if you are using EntityFramework you should use `?` after your expected `null` object  like `Client` or `StaffMember` rather than the whole query

```
var ComplaintsQuery = _context.TblComplaints.Select(p => new
    {
        ComplaintId = p.ComplaintId,
        ClientId = p.ClientId,
        ClientFullName = p.Client?.ClientFullName,
        Datecomplaintreceived = p.Datecomplaintreceived,
        StaffmemberId = p.StaffmemberId,
        StaffFullName = p.Staffmember?.StaffFullName,
    }
    ).AsQueryable();
```